# pass a php variable from one page to another page with ajax code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I dunno whether my heading is correct or not ??

While loading the shop.php page i have a variable named $curr set with values from GET like "GBP".

```
$curr = $_GET['cur'];
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cart.js"></script>
```

While loading the page the cart.js code calls another page like as follows:

```
GET http://myshop.com/cart/config-loader.php?ajax=true
```

The javascript code which loads the config-loader page is as follows:

```
var config = (function() {
        var config = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: path + '/config-loader.php',
            data: {
                "ajax": "true"
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                config = response;
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Ajax error: Edit the path in cart.js to fix.');
            }
        });
        return config;
    }());
```

I need to get the url passed as:
        http://myshop.com/cart/config-loader.php?ajax=true&curr=GBP

so that i can get the $_GET['curr'] value in config-loader.php page.

My aim is to change the value USD to any other value like GBP in config-loader.phpge:

```
if (!$config['currencyCode']) $config['currencyCode'] = 'USD';
```

How can i do this in above code ?? Help requested from experts.

Comment: `data: { "ajax": "true", "curr":"gbp" },` is that what you looking for? Also mind in your code that at first you calling the variable `cur` and then `curr`

Comment: @Athafoud I need to pass the existing php variable $curr in shop.php page to the ajax call

Comment: You need need to print the variable as @Barmar suggests into your html code, and then read it with js.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
        data: {
            "ajax": "true",
            "curr": <?php echo json_encode($curr) ?>
        },
```

Comment: Syntax Error  

"curr": <?php echo json_encode($curr) ?>

Comment: Isn't this Javascript in your PHP page?

Comment: Nope..it is in a cart.js page, which is included in a php page   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cart.js"></script>

Comment: Then it doesn't have any access to PHP variables. It sounds like you need to get it out of `location.query`.

Comment: Another option would be to use PHP sessions, and put `$curr` into `$_SESSION['curr']`.

Comment: It is loading a session: session_start(); How can i pass a session variable through the ajax call to the config-loader.php page ??

Comment: You don't need to pass it. Sessions are maintained automatically on the server.